# Dynamic Mobile Dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am attempting to dynamically populate a dropdown list from a field level script, which gathers the necessary data and fills the dropdown with new options. Generally, on non-mobile browsers, upon selecting the dropdown the old options are removed and the new ones appear. However, on mobile devices (more specifically on iPad and iPhone) the old options stay until exiting the dropdown and re-opening it. On non-mobile browser's, I've been able to use jQuery UI to get a cross-platform solution, however, this solution does not work on mobile platforms (explained below). It's not the exact code, but here is a snippet that recreates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
    <!-- for mobile devices set the width to the device width -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain" style="">
                <select id="field_4" class="sbi" name="cstate" >
                    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
                    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                    ...
                    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
                    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
                    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        <script>
            function testFill(elem) {
                jQ(elem).empty();
                jQ(elem).append(jQ("<option></option>").val("test1").text("test1"));
                jQ(elem).append(jQ("<option></option>").val("test2").text("test2"));
                jQ(elem).append(jQ("<option></option>").val("test3").text("test3"));
                jQ(elem).append(jQ("<option></option>").val("test4").text("test4"));
            }

            var sbi = document.getElementsByClassName("sbi");
            if (sbi != null && sbi.length != 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < sbi.length; i++) {
                    if (sbi[i].tagName == "SELECT") {
                        sbi[i].onclick = function() {
                            //alert("test");
                            testFill(sbi[i]);
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Working [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ux61s1y4/3/)

As stated before, this "bug" only seems to show up in mobile browsers, as well as Safari when using this method (rather then a jQuery dropdown). I've tried other options, such as jQuery Mobile dropdowns, and others, but they also did not work as intended. One option that worked was turning on AJAX, but in doing so it messed up other portions of the website, so AJAX had to be turned back off.

In order to get the issue to appear on my desktop browser, I used Safari v8.0.2 (on Mac OS X 10.10.1) with the User Agent set to "Safari iOS 8.1 - iPad" to view the JSFiddle page linked above. The issue also appears on default Safari when viewing that page, but on other browsers it updates as intended, oddly enough.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it help to call jQ(elem).selectmenu( "refresh", true ); after appending the new items? http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ux61s1y4/4/

Comment: @ezanker Unfortunately not. The problem seems to be that the appending/changing of options happens _after_ the dropdown is opened.